# Applying numeric slicer gives incorrect values as a result

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I created calculated table that would summarize data by ClaimNumber:

```
ByClaim = SUMMARIZE(fact_Losses
                        ,fact_Losses[AccidentDate]
                        ,fact_Losses[ClaimNumber]
                        ,fact_Losses[TransactionType]                       
                        ,"LossAmount", SUM(fact_Losses[PaymentAmount])
)
```

Outcome looks like this:

[image]

I generated another calculated table `Cap Slicer` that will be used as a slicer:

```
Cap Slicer = GENERATESERIES(10000,MAX(fact_Losses[LossPerClaim])+10000,10000)
```

[image]

Now I need to decrease the amount of `LossAmount` for each `ClaimNumber` by value chooses in `Cap Slicer` table. 
For that I wrote a measure:

```
Capped Loss Amount1 = 
VAR MaxLoss = MAX('Cap Slicer'[Value])
RETURN
   SUMX(
        ByClaim,
        IF(ByClaim[LossAmount]  > MaxLoss,
        MaxLoss,
        ByClaim[LossAmount] 
        ))
```

When choosing value $1,000,000 in `Cap Slicer` I'm expecting to see `Capped Loss Amount1` value of 1,000,000 for ClaimNumber `USGL00000000103`.

But for some reason it gives me 1,002,737.

Where that 2,737 comes from?

[image]

I am using SUMX function to iterate one row at a time. 
Is there other function for that that I am not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table `ByClaim` clearly has more than one row for claim number `USGL00000000103`. Your measure applies the cap per row, not per claim.

If you want the cap to apply per claim, then change your measure to:

```
Capped Loss Amount1 = 
VAR MaxLoss = 
    MAX('Cap Slicer'[Value])
VAR ActualLoss = 
   SUM( ByClaim[LossAmount] )
RETURN
    MIN ( MaxLoss, ActualLoss)
```